# Service worker registration failed -- PWA Not working after Universal Prerendering implementation in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-universal, prerender, angular9, angular-pwa

Error Throwing in the console Log
 **The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').**

```
Service worker registration failed with: DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://localhost:4000/') with script ('https://localhost:4000/ngsw-worker.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
```

Comment: Does `https://localhost:4000/ngsw-worker.js` return a js script if you open that url in  the browser?

Comment: If my answer is right, you might accept it as the right answer

Answer (score 2):

Try

`ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production, scope: './', registrationStrategy: 'registerImmediately' })`

inside `app.module.ts`

Answer (score 0):

In my case service worker was twice registered.

Once from index.html

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/serviceworker').then(function (registration) {
    console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
  }, function (err) {
    console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
  });
}
```

Second time by

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
```

inside app.module.ts

```
//ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
```

Solved my problem.